# How can i get customer add-to-cart products list with customer details

Tags: magento-1.9, addtocart, customer-attribute

I need the list of the customers who have products in cart, how can I get the list with customer email id.

Comment: @Piyush : initially customer has products in the cart, the array returns his email id, then I removed products from add-to cart, still the array returns his email id.

Comment: okay,, i just wnat to know,, How to Display PopUp Message when clicked selected Products add-to-cart Button, not for all products,, if customer clicked selected products add to cart button then only display popup message?

Comment: @TejabhagavanKollepara : Now i can't able to post as a new question, 1 month temporarily disabled by SE. Answer now after one month i will post and let you know and i will accept your answer.

Comment: @TejabhagavanKollepara https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63781/custom-option-products-popup-message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the below code in the **test.php** from root folder.

```
<?php
    require_once('app/Mage.php');
    umask(0);
    Mage::app();


    $customer_email = 'tesramat@test.com';
    $customer_detail = Mage::getModel("customer/customer");
    $customer_detail->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId());
    $customer_detail->loadByEmail($customer_email);

    $storeIds = Mage::app()->getWebsite(Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId())->getStoreIds();
    $quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->setSharedStoreIds($storeIds)->loadByCustomer($customer_detail);
    if ($quote) {

        $productsResult = array();
        foreach ($quote->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) { 

            $product = $item->getProduct(); 
            echo 'Name='.$product->getName().'<br/>';
            echo 'SKU'.$product->getSku().'<br/>';

            /*$productsResult[] = array(// Basic product data
                'product_id' => $product->getId(),
                'sku' => $product->getSku(),
                'name' => $product->getName(),
                'set' => $product->getAttributeSetId(),
                'type' => $product->getTypeId(),
                'category_ids' => $product->getCategoryIds(),
                'website_ids' => $product->getWebsiteIds()
            );*/
        }   

    }

    ?>
```

http://prntscr.com/g2iasr

http://prntscr.com/g2iaxc

Comment: You mean "" $customer_email = 'tesramat@test.com';    manually put all emails-id here, separated by comma supposed to put more than one email-id, am I right?

Comment: Login to magento admin=>customer select the customer u will be able to view the customer email    http://prntscr.com/g2iggu

Comment: You mean "" $customer_email = 'tesramat@test.com'; manually put all emails-id here, separated by comma supposed to put more than one email-id, am I right?

Comment: Is it possible can i get customer details like email-id who are all addtocart have products,  instead of put manual entering mail id?

Comment: Yes @Rathinam yo have to hard code first

Comment: please follow the steps : 1) first in the test script hard code the email id 2) login to frontend with the customer email same 3) add to cart the products 4) now run the test script

Comment: echo 'Mail-id='.$product->getEmail().'<br/>';  is right for getting customer email

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63101/discussion-between-rathinam-and-nagaraju-kasa).

Answer (score 2):

try this code -

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->getCollection()
            ->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', array('neq' => null));


$customerArr = array();
foreach($collection as $col)
{
    $products = $col->getItemsCollection();
    if ($products->count() > 0) {
        $customerArr[$col->getCustomerId()] = $col->getCustomerEmail();
    }
}
 echo '<pre>';
print_r($customerArr);
```

Comment: may i know can i use your code and get details as a csv report

Comment: this code will give you an array of customer emails, who have product in cart, you can add more details in customer  array in foreach loop. later pass this array to generate csv .

Comment: initially customer has products in the cart, the array returns his email id, then I removed products from add-to cart, still, the array returns his email id.

Comment: @Rathinam check my updated answer

Comment: hi piyush, how can i find the total weight of cart for the selected customer cart?

Comment: @Rathinam check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6550748/4349218)